# pgAdmin 3 crashes when trying to execute arbitrary sql queries

Tags: ubuntu, pgadmin

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
GNOME version 3.36.2.
pgAdmin version 3.

After successfully creating the localhost server, I'm trying to run .sql script as SQL query but the program just closes and nothing happens.

Am I missing something? What can be the possible solution to this?

Comment: pgAdmin3 is an old version. Do you have the same problem with a more recent version?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Nobody uses the more recent version; it's horrible.

Comment: @TheHeadRush whilst I have sympathy for your obvious preference for pgadmin3 over pgadmin4, to say that no-one uses pgadmin4 is absurd. I also happen to hate that Google has abandoned Play Music, but life is what it is.